# Can I reuse SSL certificate for a website on IIS for a webservice on same IIS but on port 443

Tags: ssl, iis, ip, port, certificate

Can I reuse an SSL certificate for a website on IIS (running on Port 80) for a web-service on same IIS but on port 443

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should to be OK.

The certificate is *referenced* by IIS, rather than *consumed* or *locked*, so it is available to be used by multiple applications.

When you do your bindings in IIS, you tell it what cert you want to use for SSL, but it doesn't make an exclusive claim on the certificate.

Comment: Thanks. Few more things 

1. If a webservice, over SSL, is consumed privately and not exposed to public/users. still it need a certificate? As I assume a certificate is used to inform users of authenticity of a secured (over SSL) website they are viewing on browser.

2. Do I need to put this webservice over SSL even, if it not public.

3. As you said I can reuse Certificate, but I read somewhere that certificate is a one on one binding with a domain/ip. Having said that without going into SNI concepts.

4. Apologies for asking too many questions :-)